# Load toolbar over camera

Tags: ios, camera, toolbar

I am trying to show a toolbar over the camera in ios. If I comment the line where I load the camera, the toolbar shows fine and works. So my problem is that the camera is shown over the toolbar.

I create the toolbar in xib file with all bar buttons.

Is it possible to load the toolbar over the camera? And how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

- We have to set the toolBarItems after completion of
  PresentModalViewAnimation.

> ```
>  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
>         imagePicker.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cameraBarButton,flexibleBarSpace,cancelBarButton,nil];
> }];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Overlay view with toolbar and assign it to imagePickerController. e.g.

```
overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imagePickerController.view.frame];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
overlayView.layer.opaque = NO;
overlayView.opaque = NO;
[imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayView];
```